# MSCRM for outlook 2011 full offline installation, SQL Exp and all pre-reqs

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Need a way to install all the pre-reqs for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 for Outlook, I've been working on a scripted installer application for about the last month, one of the items it installs is MSCRM for outlook, preliminary internal tests were positive, though we're starting to see some issues as we roll out to small test groups, the main issue is that these are sales reps in remote areas.

we noticed during the install for CRM, it can take several hours, because they are installing over mobile broadband (aircards) these are not urban areas so these are likely 2G / 3G connections at best.

what I'm looking for is a way to get all these packed up on some media so I can have it do a local only install, rather than just downloading it from MS, which the installer appears to do no matter which command switch I throw at it, I've consulted the deployment guide but it's lacking in this area regarding the "offline" install

heres the code I'm using to launch it

```
objShell.Run("C:\OfficeTemp\CRM\Setupclient.exe /l c:\clientinstalllog.txt INSTALLLEVEL=3 /targetdir " & CRMINSTALLDIR & " /norestart")
```

and then some sendkeys answer the rest of the questions, because I haven't found a way to do a quiet basic install, to create a full fledged "unattended" installation

any help is appreciated, even MS is not being forthcoming in giving us answers

Answer (score 1):

> echo Installing CRM 2011 prerequisites echo.
>
> START "Installing CRM 2011 prerequisites, Please wait..." /WAIT
>   .\prereq_XP\ReportViewer.exe /passive /norestart
>
> START "Installing CRM 2011 prerequisites, Please wait..." /WAIT
>   .\prereq_XP\vcredist_x86.exe /passive /norestart
>
> START "Installing CRM 2011 prerequisites, Please wait..." /WAIT
>   msiexec /i %CD%\prereq_XP\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi  /qb-!
>   REBOOT=ReallySuppress
>
> START "Installing CRM 2011 prerequisites, Please wait..." /WAIT
>   msiexec /i %CD%\prereq_XP\wllogin_32.msi /qb-! REBOOT=ReallySuppress
>
> echo Done!
>
> echo. echo.  echo Installing CRM 2011 echo.
>
> START "Installing CRM 2011, Please wait..." /WAIT
>   .\Client\SetupClient.exe /q /disableofflinecapability

Comment: thanks for the reply, care to leave a brief explanation, i see VC++2008, ms report viewer, SQL compact, looks like windows live sign in assistant and the client itself, though I do see you're doing this as a light (non-offline) install, and it appears to be a silent install, where I'm trying to do an offline-install, which seems to be my issue to begin with, sorry if I didn't clarify this in the initial question